# VSCode Python Intellisense not working with custom PYTHONPATH in .env file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I have a python project where the first line of code is something like `sys.path.insert(0, /some/path)`.  Then I try to import from this path.  The code works at runtime, but VSCode can't figure out where this package is, and so I get squigglies on the import statements, and it's unable to auto-complete any of the types or methods from the modules in this package.

I'm aware of virtual environments, but is there some way to let VSCode know about this path without going through the hassle of setting up a venv?

I've also tried using a `.env` file as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable), but I can't get that to work either.

My workspace is `D:\code\Util`

My env file is `D:\code\.env`

My python package is `D:\code\python\packagename`

My settings.json is `C:\Users\divis\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`.

The contents of my `settings.json` are:

```
{
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "python.envFile": "D:/code/.env"
}
```

The contents of my `.env` file are:

```
PYTHONPATH=python
```

Then in my code I do this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'D:/code/python')
import packagename
```

and PyLint can't find it.  Is one of the steps above incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with a directory format like this

- C:\someCode\some_lib\some_utility.py
- C:\someCode\some_app\my_application.py

```
#import some_lib/some_utility   # pylance shows error
```

The solution for me was to add something like this to settings.json

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "../"
    ]
```